# Figure out how number of times a certain time in UTC has occurred between 2 timestamps?

Tags: javascript, timezone, utc

I have 2 timestamps in UTC (resolution = seconds). Let's say I want to determine how many times "2pm UTC" has occurred between those 2 timestamps, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do expensive iterations. You know you'll see at least one occurrence of 14:00UTC for every day in the interval, then you just need to account for the remainders.

```js
const MIN = 60 * 1000,
     HOUR = MIN * 60,
      DAY = HOUR * 24;


const numCnt = (start,end) => {
  start = new Date(start);
  end = new Date(end);
  if(end < start) {
    let tmp = end;
    end = start;
    start = tmp;
    console.error('get your s**t together');
  }
  let buff = '';
  let log = x => buff += (x||'')+'\n'
  log('Start '+start.toISOString()+'\nEnd   '+end.toISOString());
  let num = Math.floor((end-start) / DAY);
  log(`Ran for ${num} days, at least ${num} occurrences of 14:00UTC`);



  const startHours = (start%DAY)/HOUR;
  const endHours = (end%DAY)/HOUR;
  log(`Started at ${startHours}UTC, ended at ${endHours}UTC`);
  if((startHours < 14) && (endHours > 14)) {
    log(`Extra 14UTC on the front end`);
    num++;
  }
  else if((startHours > endHours) && (endHours > 14)) {
    log(`Extra 14UTC on the back end`);
    num++;
  }
  else if(startHours == endHours && endHours == 14) {
    log(`Started and ended at exactly 14UTC, fence post problem`);
    num++;
  }
  log(`Total occurrences = ${num}\n`);
  console.log(buff);
}

numCnt('2019-02-18T13:59:59Z','2021-02-18T13:59:59Z');
numCnt('2019-02-18T13:59:59Z','2021-02-18T14:00:01Z');
numCnt('2019-02-18T14:01:01Z','2021-02-18T14:00:01Z');
numCnt('2019-02-18T14:01:01Z','2021-02-18T13:59:59Z');
numCnt('2019-02-18T14:00:00Z','2021-02-18T14:00:00Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
function getOccurrences(start_timestamp,end_timestamp) {
    // Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp
    // multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds.
    let start_date = new Date(start_timestamp * 1000);

    let day = ("0" + start_date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);

    let month = ("0" + (start_date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    let year = start_date.getUTCFullYear();

    let iterStr = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T14:00:00.000Z';

    let newStart = new Date(iterStr);

    let iter = Math.trunc(newStart.getTime() / 1000)

    let iterStart = iter

    let occurrences = 0

    while (iter <= end_timestamp) {
        occurrences++
        iter += 86400
    }

    if ((iterStart < start_timestamp) && (occurrences > 0)) {
        occurrences--
    }

    return occurrences
}
```

Comment: this line seems incorrect? `occurences = truncated value of (end-start)% 86400` I'm assuming you mean (end-start)/864000 rounded down to nearest whole number.

Also the code doesn't seem to make sense? Example: start = 1pm, end = 1pm the next day. We want to see how many times we cross 2pm. The answer should be "1". Under this algo, the answer would end up being 2 since we would increment ocurrences by 1.

Comment: apologies @Roymunson. I edited the answer above.